# How do I calculate the number of positive days?

Tags: powerbi

I have the following measure:

```
no_positive_bets = 
COUNTAX(
    FILTER(
        'belgarath match_', 
        'belgarath match_'[ogion_pnl] >= 0
    ), 
    'belgarath match_'[ogion_pnl]
)
```

Assuming there is a field called `'belgarath match_'[date]` how would I group `'belgarath match_'[ogion_pnl]` by day so that I can work out the number of positive days?

---

**Edit:**

By way of some sample data:

```
+-----+------------+-----------+
| id_ |    date    | ogion_pnl |
+-----+------------+-----------+
|   1 | 01/01/2020 |       100 |
|   2 | 02/01/2020 |       100 |
|   3 | 02/01/2020 |       -50 |
|   4 | 03/01/2020 |       100 |
|   5 | 03/01/2020 |      -150 |
+-----+------------+-----------+
```

The current snippet I have will return `3` because three rows are positive. However I would like it to return `2` as the first two days are positive.

Comment: Can you make your requirement bit more clear by adding some sample data with your required output from them?

Comment: @mkRabbani - sure! Added data.

Comment: What count you need if row 5 also positive. Are you looking for consecutive positive rows should count as 1?

Comment: @mkRabbani - if row 5 was positive then 03/01 would be positive so that would mean every one of the three days across the five rows would be positive

Comment: Hi @Jossy, please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it may help..

no_positive_bets = COUNTAX(FILTER('belgarath match_', [ogion_pnl] >= 0), [ogion_pnl])

Answer (score 0):

Create this below **Custom Column** First-

```
is possitive = 

VAR current_date = your_table_name[date]

VAR current_date_sum =  
CALCULATE(
    SUM(your_table_name[ogion_pnl]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(your_table_name),
        your_table_name[date] = current_date
    )
) 

RETURN IF(current_date_sum >= 0, 1, 0)
```

Now create this below **Measure**-

```
number of possitive day = 
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT(your_table_name[date]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(your_table_name),
        your_table_name[is possitive] = 1
    )
)
```

Now add the measure **number of possitive day** to a card and the output will be as below-

[image]

Comment: Hi. Thanks for this. I'm not looking for positive rows though - I'm looking for positive DAYS. I was thinking I need to group ```date``` with the sum of ```ogion_pnl``` and then count those rows?